# Does spark load the entire table in memory if select condition is based on RDD transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, directed-acyclic-graphs

```
DataSet<Row> a = spark.read().format("com.memsql.spark.connector").option("query", "select * from a");
a = a.filter((row)-> row.x = row.y)
Sring xstring = "...select all values of x from a and make comma separated string"
DataSet<Row> b = spark.read().format("com.memsql.spark.connector").option("query", "select * from b where x in " + xstring);
b.show()
```

In this case as spark would load the entire b table in memory and then filter out xtring rows or it actually create that xstring and then load a subset of table b in memory when we call show

Comment: nothing loaded in to memory till you call action on it

Comment: show is an action . When it sees show does it load entire b and then filter out sztring rows or 1st time loads string rows , that's my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When memsql is queried using `option("query", "select * from .......")` the entire result (not table) will be read from memsql into executors. The MemSQL Spark Connector 2.0 supports column and filter pushdown for which the SQL needs to have the filter and join condition rather than applying filter and join on dataframe. In your example predicate push down will be used. In your example - entire table 'a' will be read because there is no filter condition, xstring will be build, then only that part of table 'b' is read that matches `x in (...)` condition.

Here is memsql documentation [explaining this](https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/guides/client-and-application/third-party-integrations/spark-connector/#changes-from-memsql-spark-connector-1-x).